# Repetition of Rows N times using Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a input as in Excel sheet

| Date | ISIN | Issuer | Type | Maturit | New Yield |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-May-2022 | AB1234A | Abcd Ltd | Corporate | 15-Jun-2022 | Formula |
| 20-May-2022 | AB1234H | GHIJ Ltd | Corporate | 31-May-2022 | Formula |

I want output as follows where date has to be incremented and repetition of rows after a set of rows , my input can be of any number of rows:

| Date | ISIN | Issuer | Type | Maturit | New Yield |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-May-2022 | AB1234A | Abcd Ltd | Corporate | 15-Jun-2022 | Formula |
| 20-May-2022 | AB1234H | GHIJ Ltd | Corporate | 31-May-2022 | Formula |
| 21-May-2022 | AB1234A | Abcd Ltd | Corporate | 15-Jun-2022 | Formula |
| 21-May-2022 | AB1234H | GHIJ Ltd | Corporate | 31-May-2022 | Formula |
| 22-May-2022 | AB1234A | Abcd Ltd | Corporate | 15-Jun-2022 | Formula |
| 22-May-2022 | AB1234H | GHIJ Ltd | Corporate | 31-May-2022 | Formula |

This is the Code:

```
Sub Repeat()
   Dim i As Long
   
   For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
      Rows(i).Copy
      Rows(i).Resize(Range("G" & i)).Insert
   Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So not entirely certain of the use of this but... this should get you a long way to what you want (assumes dates are stored as dates not strings):

```
Sub RepeatResponse()
    finalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    numofRows = finalRow - 1
    numOfCopies = 2

    Range(finalRow + 1 & ":" & finalRow + 1 + numOfCopies * numofRows - 1).EntireRow.Insert
    
    arrayHelper = Range("A2:F" & finalRow).FormulaR1C1Local
    For j = 1 To numOfCopies
        For i = 1 To numofRows
            arrayHelper(i, 1) = arrayHelper(i, 1) + 1
        Next i
        Range("A" & finalRow + 1 + (j - 1) * numofRows & ":F" & finalRow + 1 + (j) * numofRows - 1).FormulaR1C1Local = arrayHelper
    Next j
End Sub
```

Pulling this apart a little:

```
    finalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    numofRows = finalRow - 1
    numOfCopies = 2
```

finalRow will be 3 in your input example with numofRows being 2 (excluding the title row) and in the example you had those rows copied twice (once for 21st once for 22nd).

```
    Range(finalRow + 1 & ":" & finalRow + 1 + numOfCopies * numofRows - 1).EntireRow.Insert
```

this selects the number of rows we need to insert to put the data in.  if you don't need rows inserted (i.e. there is no data after the table or need for new rows for some other reason) then remove this line

this section sets up an array (for efficiency on larger runs and cycles the number of copies needed and the date changing

```
    arrayHelper = Range("A2:F" & finalRow).FormulaR1C1Local
    For j = 1 To numOfCopies
        For i = 1 To numofRows
            arrayHelper(i, 1) = arrayHelper(i, 1) + 1
        Next i
        Range("A" & finalRow + 1 + (j - 1) * numofRows & ":F" & finalRow + 1 + (j) * numofRows - 1).FormulaR1C1Local = arrayHelper
    Next j
```

Worth saying that if the number of copies is large then the array should be used more to increase efficiency.  For the moment I believe this will be sufficient though

Comment: Do you also know Python ? Actually problem I am facing is with VBA internet explorer web scrapping , from  15 Jun 22 microsoft has stopped IE and I dont wanna use selenium

Comment: not in a useful way honestly, I did a webscrape thing a couple of years back that worked well for what I wanted but otherwise no

Comment: I know webscrape , but only in Internet explorer , now that is also not working.. Do u know Python Programming  ? I am writing codes in Python but sometimes not working

Comment: like i say only very minor amount, you can ask for help on here, i'm sure there are better people than i to do it!  from python i used mouse and keyboard control to webscrape but it took a long time!